# Jquery animate () issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a jquery animation, when you click on one of the buttons the hidden div slides from `left: -650px;` to `left: 0px;`[click here to see example](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/wrS5Q/) However i noticed when you click on another button to reveal another hidden div, the pervious hidden div does not go back to it's original position of `left: -650px;` it stay at left: 0; does anyone know what i need to added in order to achieve this...?

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="top-block">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="one" href="#" class="proBtn">block</a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="two" href="#" class="proBtn">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="three" href="#" class="proBtn">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="four" href="#" class="proBtn">Lists</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="proBtn">hello</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="proBtn">test</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- HOME SECTION -->
        <div id="one-bck" class="mid-block fadeInLeft" style="background:green;"></div>
        <div id="two-bck" class="mid-block fadeInLeft" style="background:red;"></div>
        <div id="three-bck" class="mid-block fadeInLeft"></div>
        <div id="four-bck" class="mid-block fadeInLeft"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.proBtn').click(function () {
        $('li').removeClass('active');
        $('li a').removeClass('blue');
        $(this).parent("li").addClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('blue');
    });

    $('#one').click(function () {
        $('#two-bck').animate({
            left: '-650px;',
            opacity: 0
        }, 500).removeClass('animated');
        $('#three-bck').animate({
            left: '-650px;',
            opacity: 0
        }, 500).removeClass('animated');
        $('#four-bck').animate({
            left: '-650px;',
            opacity: 0
        }, 500).removeClass('animated');
        $('#one-bck').addClass('animated').animate({
            left: '0px',
            opacity: 1
        }, 500);
    });

    $('#two').click(function () {
        $('#one-bck').animate({
            left: '-650px;',
            opacity: 0
        }, 500).removeClass('animated');
        $('#three-bck').animate({
            left: '-650px;',
            opacity: 0
        }, 500).removeClass('animated');
        $('#four-bck').animate({
            left: '-650px;',
            opacity: 0
        }, 1500).removeClass('animated');
        $('#two-bck').addClass('animated').animate({
            left: '0px',
            opacity: 1
        }, 500);;
    });

    $('#three').click(function () {
        $('#one-bck').animate({
            left: '-650px;',
            opacity: 0
        }, 500).removeClass('animated');
        $('#two-bck').animate({
            left: '-650px;',
            opacity: 0
        }, 500).removeClass('animated');
        $('#four-bck').animate({
            left: '-650px;',
            opacity: 0
        }, 500).removeClass('animated');
        $('#three-bck').addClass('animated').animate({
            left: '-650px;',
            opacity: 0
        }, 500);
    });

});
```

Comment: Please stop abusing [html5] and [css3] tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can really try to simplify this apart from just fixing the css and removeClass issue.  Instead of binding event handlers to each of those ids can be a mintenance headache as they all do the same thing. You can add a data attribute to the anchor tags i.e `data-target="#three-bck"` and select them to be animated. It can all go in just one event handler.

HTML:

```
      <ul>
        <li><a id="one" href="#" class="proBtn" data-target="#one-bck">block</a>

        </li>
        <li><a id="two" href="#" class="proBtn" data-target="#two-bck">test</a>

        </li>
        <li><a id="three" href="#" class="proBtn" data-target="#three-bck">test</a>

        </li>
        <li><a id="four" href="#" class="proBtn" data-target="#four-bck">Lists</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="proBtn">hello</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="proBtn">test</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.proBtn').click(function () {
        $('li').removeClass('active').find('a').removeClass('blue'); //chain it
        var $this = $(this); //cache this first
        $this.addClass('blue').closest("li").addClass('active');

        $('.mid-block.animated').animate({ //start animate for reverse in case if there is anything already selected
            left: '-650px',
            opacity: 0
        }, 500, function(){
           $(this).removeClass('animated'); //once done remove its class
        }).promise().done(function () { //once this is done start animating your target by selecting the target element from its own data attribute
            $($this.data('target')).addClass('animated').stop(true, true).animate({
                left: '0px',
                opacity: 1
            }, 500);
        });
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhrUf/)**

Comment: Thanks man, i'm still pretty new to Jquery so at the moment i'm bulking my code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semi-colon after the 'px' on `left:'-650px;'` .

Should only be `left:'-650px'` .

Comment: Oh I see. that's because the .removeClass is being called and removing the display: block before the animation barely starts.